# Looking for details regarding ROS1 dispatching of subscription callbacks

Tags: ros-noetic

I've run into some issues and confusion on serious subtleties with rospy, subscription callbacks, the use of rate.sleep(), spin(), rospy.sleep(). Does anyone know of a writeup that explains exactly how the dispatching of callbacks works in rospy. I gather that rospy is multi threaded, and that there are threads to handle callbacks, and some other little facts that I try to put together into a cogent picture. I don't really want to start reading the ROS code but maybe that's what it will take. Here are some questions that are related:

- if a subscription callback includes sleep or other IO, can you create a race condition?
- if a callback us an instance method and uses instance variables, or if it's just a function and uses python globals, is that going to cause problems?
- What problems can occur if a callback (say odom) publishes cmd_vel directly during the callback?

I've dug around answers.ros, google, some books. But I can't find a clear explanation of how callback dispatching works with rospy and with threads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion about rospy callback handling [on this page](https://answers.ros.org/question/9543/rospy-threading-model/).

The bottom line from that discussion is that your subscribe callback needs to be thread-safe. When there is more than one publisher to the topic, rospy may invoke the callback simultaneously from multiple threads.

While it is permitted to call `rospy.sleep()` inside a subscribe callback, I consider it a poor design decision, because blocking the callback execution often leads to poor performance. A better design pattern is to use a `rospy.Rate` or a `rospy.Timer` outside of the subscribe callback.

Comment: Thanks...I did come across it but wasn't sure to believe it given the date. But anyway it would be nice to have a single cogent document somewhere explaining this important point. I tried to create an small example program to demonstrate a race condition in a program subscriberd to two different topics and callback. I haven't succeeded yet in showing a race condition.